# Cannot find interface declaration for BaseType / Attempting to use forward declaration for BaseType

Tags: objective-c, c, llvm, xcode4.5

I am stuck between the `Cannot find interface declaration for BaseType superclass of MyType` and `Attempting to use forward declaration for BaseType as superclass of MyType` errors.

I was creating a new subclass and imported the headers of my base type. I got this error: `Cannot find interface declaration for BaseType superclass of MyType`. Having got this error before, I forward-declared my class with the `@class BaseType` statement. Then instead of the first error, I've got the second error: `Attempting to use forward declaration for BaseType as superclass of MyType`.

When forward declared, removing the `#import BaseType.h` changes nothing, I still get the second error. I have found solutions to both errors, and I end up with the other error of the two when I apply the solution (e.g. forward declaring, or importing header). What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've ended up moving the `#import` declarations to implementation (.m) files, and keeping the headers clean from `#import` statements except its own superclasses. There was probably a infinite recursion of imports, and moving them away from implementation worked. In the header files, I've forward-declared the classes that I needed to reference in the interface, and nothing else. It worked.